# Android develop on virtual machine

Tags: android

I have Hyper-V 2008 R2 and VM with Windows server 2008 R2 Datacenter OS on VM.
I try latest Android studio on them but can't start Emulator cause I can't install HAXM and can't go to Hyper-V 2008 R2 BIOS VM to see if VT-X it's enabled. After that I have install Xamarin/Visual studio 2017 and can start emulator, but its so slow. I try install other image Google API Atom x86, ARM/EARABI. Does anyone know which Android develop platform can work good on Hyper-V 2008 R2 Virtual machine?
I'm new to Android develop so for me it's same Android studio or Xamarin, any suggestion would be great.

Comment: You could try GenyMotion (personal is free).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Genymotion Community Edition. Genymotion is based on VirtualBox. If VirtualBox is working on your platform, then you should definitely check it out: [link](https://www.genymotion.com/).